# MVC3 Html.BeginForm not rendering for a page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a web page (one of many). But on this particular web page the following doesn't render.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
     <h1>bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</h1>
 }
```

The only difference between this and other web pages is that I have dynamically created this link to this page with jQuery rather than hardcoding the link on the page. When I check the link it looks like this:

```
<a href="/adminStats/Edit?PartitionKey=P22&amp;RowKey=01-01-0001">Edit</a>
```

Is there something about BeginForm that can't see the page address so it doesn't create the form link?

Robert

Comment: how are u passing link address?

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem. Check for nested form tags.

Comment: I added an end form tag (</form>) to the top of my modal view (above the new form) to quickly verify this was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that if you don't specify the route values, `BeginForm` will try to create the form action based on the current request context. That being said, if that's not the current view's URL then it shouldn't matter. So, in the end, I would say that that link has no effect on `BeginForm`, but something that `BeginForm` needs from behind the scenes (out of your control) is not available, and thus `BeginForm` is silently failing.

You can try exploring the [source](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/66799#288009) for `BeginForm` and see what potentially might be missing...