# ActionResult not being called in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

The ActionResult in the controller is not being called. Setting a breakpoint shows that the ActionResult fileUpload is not being hit.

View and controller code below: (FileUpload.aspx/FileUploadController.cs):

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("fileUpload", "FileUpload", 
                FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"  }))
           {%>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />  
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Upload File" />
        <span style="color: red; font-weight: bold">
            <%=TempData["UploadValidationMessage_Failure"]%>
        </span><span style="color: Green; font-weight: bold"> 
            <%=TempData["UploadValidationMessage_Success"]%>
        </span> 
        <%} %>


/// <summary>
    /// n/a
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>set FileUpload view return value</returns>
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("FileUpload");
    }

        /// <summary>
        /// Uploads the file and store it in ~\Uploads directory.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult fileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {

            if (file.ContentLength > 0 & isXLSXFile > 0)
            {
                string filePath = Path.Combine(
                  Server.MapPath("~/Uploads"),
                  Path.GetFileName("ExcelFileUpload.xlsx"));  // save as new filename
                try
                {
                    file.SaveAs(filePath);
                    TempData["UploadValidationMessage_Success"] = "File upload succeeded";

                    return View();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    TempData["UploadValidationMessage_Failure"] = "Failed to upload the file " + e.ToString();

                        return View();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    TempData["UploadValidationMessage_Failure"] = "Filename missing or filename extension is not .xlsx";

                    return View();
                }
    }
    }
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}.aspx/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
          "Root",
          "",
          new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
        );
    }
```

Comment: Could you give us more detail? Also, please include the routes found in your global.asax, as likely is caused by a routing issue.

Comment: public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}.aspx/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
              "Root",
              "",
              new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
            );
        }

Comment: is there additional detail that your require?

Comment: Okay solved the problem. Turns out it was a problem with changes I made to the Site.Master file. Inspect element showed that the <form> tag was not being generated by Html.BeginForm. Found a similar issue on Stackoverflow -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6946051/mvc3-beginform-not-rendering-form-tags.

Comment: Ahh, never would have guessed that. Please answer your own question and mark it as the answer. Thanks.